# Is there any way for somebody to access my source code from an IPA file of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I have developed an app for a company for internal use and their IT department has asked for the ipa file to do some security analysis.

I'm okay to provide that but I'm wondering if somebody can access my source code from the ipa file?

Comment: May start with [a quick search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=reverse+engineer+ipa&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) - "get your source code", no, get something which could be re-compiled, maybe

Answer (score 0):

Each .ipa file includes a binary, not a source code so there’s no general way to get it from the .ipa file.

Otherwise, they can do reverse engineering with your .ipa file with standard command-line tools for reverse engineering iOS and macOS apps.

[Source](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/363-how-to-reverse-engineer-os-x-and-ios-software)